# How to filter model by hour in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter and count employee attendance.

I have a table like this:

```
attedance table:
+-----+-----------------------+----------+-----------+
|  id |                  time |   status |    emp_id |
+-----+-----------------------+----------+-----------+
|   1 |    2018-04-17 7:03:40 |        1 |         1 |
|   2 |    2018-04-18 7:10:50 |        1 |         1 |
|   3 |    2018-04-19 5:05:32 |        1 |         1 |
|   4 |    2018-04-20 7:07:44 |        1 |         1 |
|   5 |    2018-04-18 7:10:50 |        1 |         2 |
+-----+-----------------------+----------+-----------+
```

my objective is to filter all attendance data.

got solution with 
`models.model.objects.filter(emp_id=1).count()`

its return `4` in my case.

but also filter that `time(hour)` must `> 6`

trying to add `datetime.datetime(time).time() > 6` to the filter but its not work.

any can help or suggest me how to make it happen?...

or have other best scenario like use forloop,

or it's not possible?...

Comment: i think better solution with forloop, but i don't know how to do it. any can help?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__hour`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#hour) to filter by the hour:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    emp_id=1,
    time__hour__gt=6
).count()
```

Comment: cannot use `>=` ?... since `=` is equal right?... so it will only show equal `6` CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

you can filter like this

> model.objects.filter(time__hour__gte=6).filter(emp_id=1).count()

Comment: `gte` is `>=`, the OP wants `>`.

Comment: `__gte` is `>=` so `__gt` is `>`